# SLAM localizing methods based on camera?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, pose, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any SLAM methods that can create a map from the camera output based on colors in ROS?
Im working on a project where I can only get an absolute position by using lines that are drawn on the floor, just like a football field.

Most SLAM methods Ive seen like this one: https://vision.in.tum.de/research/vslam/lsdslam rely a lot on depth-perception.
I am just wondering which slam methods can detect (big & long) lines on the floor. I cant rely on walls or objects being detected mostly because the robot sometimes has to navigate in huge halls where the walls are really far away.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284429/slam-localizing-methods-based-on-camera?/) by [HaroldVD](https://answers.ros.org/users/33995/haroldvd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are not able to apply `Gmapping` directly for this application because it does not give a promising result when enough features are not available in the sensor field of view. `RGB-D SLAM` also will not work as you have repetitive patterns on your RGB images.

I think your problem seems easy than general SLAM problem. You can extract those line segments using a line detector from RGB image. Then use ICP algorithm to align those frames.

If you need a more robust result, you can use the same method with  `Rao-Blackwellized particle filter` that is used in `Gmapping`. But you need an accurate data association strategy to work with RBPF.

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1